# A form per table row, but also form for the entire table

Tags: html, forms, nested

I can't seem to figure out how to run a form for each individual row but at the same time have a form that handles every items in the table. Ex.:

deleteSelected form would control the bulk actions,
changeStatus form would control individual items

```
<form id="deleteSelected">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="deleteSelected[]"/></td>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td>
                <form id="changeStatus">
                    <select name="item_id">
                        <option value="option1">option1</option>
                        <option value="option2">option2</option>
                        <option value="option3">option3</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <table>
</form>
```

I know this is wrong since you cannot nest forms for obvious reasons, but this is what i'm trying to accomplish.

A possible solution I have encountered is to create a invisible form filled by javascript with all the checked items id's then do a PHP explode to the POST. But its seems more like a hack than a fix. Any other way??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

form under inner form is not valid so you can use JavaScript function to load page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changestatus(value)
{
    window.location.href="actionurl.php?sendvalue="+value;
}
</script>
```

call this function onchange event of select box like this

```
<form id="deleteSelected">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="deleteSelected[]"/></td>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td>
               <!-- <form id="changeStatus">-->
                    <select name="item_id" onchange="changestatus(this.value);">
                        <option value="option1">option1</option>
                        <option value="option2">option2</option>
                        <option value="option3">option3</option>
                    </select>
              <!--  </form>-->
            </td>
        </tr>
    <table>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function changestatus(value)
{
    window.location.href="actionurl.php?sendvalue="+value;
}
</script>
```